# Is $|abc|+|bcd|+|abd|+|acd|$ a norm on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, symmetric-polynomials

We know about [$L_p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) that average of the $p$-th powers of a vector is a norm:

$$ |x|_p = \sqrt[p]{ \frac{x_1^p + \dots + x_n^p}{p}} $$

This means for example, this norm satisfies the triangle inequality (in this case, it's the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)):

$$ |x+y|_p  = \sqrt[p]{ \frac{(x_1+y_1)^p + \dots + (x_n+y_n)^p}{p}}
\leq   \sqrt[p]{ \frac{x_1^p + \dots + x_n^p}{p}}
+ 
\sqrt[p]{ \frac{y_1^p + \dots + y_n^p}{p}} = |x|_p + |y|_p $$

I'd like to know if we could use other symmetric polynomials as norms.  Let's define a function:

$$ f(x) =  \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} |x_i x_j x_k|^3 $$

Does this satisfy triangle inequality?  E.g. is $f(x+y) < f(x) + f(y)$, where $x_i, y_i > 0$ ?  And if it is a norm we typically have constants such that:

$$ A ||\cdot ||_1 < ||\cdot||_2 < B ||\cdot||_1 $$

and I'd like to know possible constants $A$ and $B$, not even optimal.

---

Originally my question was if $|abc|+|bcd|+|abd|+|acd|$ is a norm on vectors $(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and to compare it to the $L^3$ norm.

Please put absolute value signs as needed.  At least, what I've written s hould be true for $p$ even.

Comment: Did you mean $(x_n + y_n)^p$ in your version of Minkowski instead of $(x_n + n_1)^p$? Also, your expression for the $p$-norm isn't correct.

Comment: It's not *the* $p$-norm (it is up to a factor $p^{1/p}$), but it is *a* norm (for $p\geq 1$).

Comment: your expressions with $x_ix_jx_k$ $i<j<k$ are 
1) not $1$-homogeneous
2) not convex 
3) are 0 for the canonical basis
so they satisfy precisely 0 conditions out of 3 for being a norm.

Comment: What is your question? The question in the title is different from the (rather unclear) question in the body of your post. One very simple criterion for a norm is that it must restrict to a norm on any subspace. Your proposed norms on $\Bbb{R}^4$ do not restrict to a norm on the $x_1$-axis.

Answer (score 6):

Let $p\geq 1$ and 
$$ f(x) =  \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} |x_i x_j x_k|^p $$
Then $f(1,0,\ldots,0)=0$ so it can not be a norm, let us fix that by redefining $f$ as $$ \tilde f(x) =  \sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n} |x_i x_j x_k|^p $$
Now, $\tilde f(\alpha x)= \alpha^{3p} f(x)$ for $\alpha>0$ so it is still not norm, let us fix this by redefining $\tilde f$ as
$$ \hat f(x) =  \Big(\sum_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n} |x_i x_j x_k|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{3p}}.$$
Now, by computing the Hessian of $\hat f$, you will see that it is not always positive semi-definite. Hence $\hat f$ is not convex and therefore not a norm (and I don't think this can be fixed).

> **Conclusion:** $f$ is not a norm and not even close from being so.